# sed to replace "_", "&", "$" with "\_", "\&", "\$" respectively

Tags: linux, latex, sed

In writing latex, usually there is a bibliography file, which sometimes contains `_`, `&`, or `$`. For example, the journal name "Nature Structural & Molecular Biology", the article title "Estimating The Cost Of New Drug Development: Is It Really $802 Million?", and the volume number "suppl_2".

So I need to convert these symbols into `\_`, `\&`, and `\$` respectively, i.e. adding a backslash in front, so that latex compiler can correctly identify them. I want to use sed to do the conversion. So I tried

```
sed 's/_/\_/' <bib.txt >new.txt
```

but the generated new.txt is exactly the same as bib.txt. I thought `_` and `\` needed to be escaped, so I tried

```
sed 's/\_/\\\_/' <bib.txt >new.txt
```

but no hope either. Can somebody help? Thanks.

Comment: My apologies, I misread it as I was editing.

Comment: If you already have some of those characters escaped, then your regex will need to check that the previous character wasn't a '\'.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're running into some difficulties due to how the shell handles strings. The backslash needs to be doubled:

```
sed 's/_/\\_/g'
```

Note that I've also added a 'g' to indicate that the replacement should applied globally on the lines, not just to the first match.

To handle all three symbols, use a character class:

```
sed 's/[_&$]/\\&/g'
```

(The ampersand in the replacement text is a special character referring to the matched text, not a literal ampersand character.)

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/\([_&$]\)/\\\1/g'
```

e.g.

```
eu-we1:~/tmp# cat zzz
bla__h&thisis&not the $$end
eu-we1:~/tmp# sed 's/\([_&$]\)/\\\1/g' < zzz
bla\_\_h\&thisis\&not the \$\$end
eu-we1:~/tmp#
```

Comment: and don't do inplace seds, u never know. do sed 's/\([_&$]\)/\\\1/g' < src.tex > dst.tex

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your `\`.  Like this: `sed 's/_/\\_/' new.txt`.

Edit: Also, to modify new.txt in place, you need to pass sed the `-i` flag:

`sed -iBAK 's/_/\\_/' new.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape it twice.

```
➜  8080667  sed 's/_/\\_/' new.txt
In writing latex, usually there is a bibliography file, which sometimes contains \_, &, or $. For example, the journal name "Nature Structural & Molecular Biology", the article title "Estimating The Cost Of New Drug Development: Is It Really $802 Million?", and the volume number "suppl_2".
➜  8080667
```